# ReactJS how to close select dropdown on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have doubts how to close the select dropdown on screen orientation change. For now I have  the listener that handles the state when the orientation is changed:

```
const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState('portrait');

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', setScreenOrientation)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('orientationchange', setScreenOrientation)
    }
  }, [])



const setScreenOrientation = () => {
    if(window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches){
      console.log('orientation: portrait');
      setOrientation('portrait');
    }

    if(window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches){
      console.log('orientation: landscape');
      setOrientation('landscape');
    }
  }

 return (<Dropdown
          options={data}
          center
          onSelect={handleSelect}
          value={data.store_id}
          selected="key"
          screenOrientation={screenOrientation}
        />)
```

Dropdown component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import styles from './styles.module.scss';

export const Dropdown = ({
  options,
  center,
  onSelect,
  value,
  selected,
  screenOrientation
}) => {

  return (
    <div
      className={classnames(
        styles.dropdown
      )}
    >
      <select
        onChange={onSelect}
        value={value}
      >
        {options && 
          Object.entries(options)
            .map(([k, v]) => (
              <option
                key={v}
                value={selected === 'key' ? k : v}
              >
                {v}
              </option>
            ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But I don't know how to imlement this functionality when the screen is changed to close the dropdown if it's opened?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which dropdown?

Comment: @GustavoCesário I have Select dropdown component.

Comment: You should update your snippet to show how you're using your dropdown. But all I can say now is that you could try to trigger the "blur" method from the select component.

Comment: @GustavoCesário I update the code. I'm new in this and if you can send me sample code i will appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the orientation variable in the bracket

```
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', setScreenOrientation)
        return () => {
             document.removeEventListener('orientationchange', setScreenOrientation)       
     }
     }, [orientation])
```

Comment: I will add it, but I need more information how to use it in the dropdown component.

Comment: I think your variable is wrong on the return Dropdown component, instead of `{screenOrientation}` try `{orientation}`, right now it seems that your orientation always will be the initial state 'portrait'

Comment: That's not it, it will just remove and add the listener whenever the orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, pass the state "orientation" as props to your Dropdown component.

```
 return (<Dropdown
          options={data}
          center
          onSelect={handleSelect}
          value={data.store_id}
          selected="key"
          orientation={orientation}
        />)
```

Then you will have to add a "ref" to your select component. With the "ref" you will be able to call the .onBlur() method whenever the orientation changes. To do that you will also need an useEffect();

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import styles from './styles.module.scss';

export const Dropdown = ({
  options,
  center,
  onSelect,
  value,
  selected,
  orientation
}) => {

  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
     if(ref.current)
        ref.current.blur();
  }, [orientation]);

  return (
    <div
      className={classnames(
        styles.dropdown
      )}
    >
      <select
        onChange={onSelect}
        value={value}
        ref={ref}
      >
        {options && 
          Object.entries(options)
            .map(([k, v]) => (
              <option
                key={v}
                value={selected === 'key' ? k : v}
              >
                {v}
              </option>
            ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```